# What does super.run() mean within a thread in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, super

I don't really get the meaning of `super.run();`and`super.handleMessage(msg);`
Are they necessaary?

Where should my code be written? Before `super.run();`/`super.handleMessage(msg);` or after them?

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
    }
}.start();
```

/

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg); 
    }
};
```

Comment: in the case of Thread super.run() is not necessary. Any call to an object's super method of the same name will call the method in the class your class inherits from. in the case of Thread(), it provides an empty run method which doesn't do anything. so it's not required.  I'm not sure how the Handler works but I'm guessing its not required here either.

Answer (score 2):

**Question**

> 1. I don't really get the meaning of `super.run()` and `super.handleMessage(msg)` Are they necessaary?
> 2. Where should my code be written? Before `super.run()` or after them?

**Answer - 1**

This is ***unnecessary*** in the code in question.

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
    }
}.start();

public class Thread implements Runnable
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            target.run();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`super.run` is call `Thread` class. Therefore, it is not necessary because there is empty function.

**Answer - 2**

Please refer to the ***answer -1***, you don't have to worry about it.

However, if your `super.x` is implemented, you will have to write code that depends on function.

Answer (score 1):

The Thread class documentation clearly says

```
public void run()

If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

Subclasses of Thread should override this method.
```

Similarly, Handler Java docs are not so clear, but if you see Handler's handleMessage method code, its empty.

```
    /**
     * Subclasses must implement this to receive messages.
     */
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
```

So for both methods, calling super is not required. They both do nothing.

Your second question, answer depends on your requirement. Java does not restrict that call to super method has to be the first line of code ( except when you are writing constructors, then super constructor has to be called before any other line/ piece of code in sub class constructor).  If you need to process some logic before the super class method, you are free to do so. You could also call super method in between your method code if you want.  So you can call super method anywhere in the overridden method. You need to take a look at what super class method does and how do you need it to decide on when to call it.

Answer (score 0):

when you are writing `@Override  public void run()` you are overriding the base run method so it will run what ever present on it.
In below example it will print inside run.If you pass target in constructor and call `super.run()` then `target.run()` method got called.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new test()){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // super.run();
                System.out.println("inside run");
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
class test implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside target");

    }

 }
```